# "_" character in Swift functions/methods

Tags: ios, swift, method-signature

I'm reading some chapters of the Apple's [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) and I find that methods and functions signatures in the reference have an `_` character as argument(s), for instance the `print` function:

> print(_:separator:terminator:)

However, I don't find what this character exactly means.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is the syntax that allows callers to omit the *external parameter name*:

> [Omitting External Parameter Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166)
>
> If you do not want to use an external name for the second or subsequent parameters of a function, write an underscore (`_`) instead of an explicit external name for that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

See this section in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158):

> Omitting External Parameter Names
>
> If you do not want to use an external name for the second or subsequent parameters of a function, write an underscore (_) instead of an explicit external name for that parameter.

This character indicates that the identifier of the argument isn't required in the method call:

This method

```
func sayHello(personName: String, alreadyGreeted: Bool) -> String
```

is referred to as

```
sayHello(_:alreadyGreeted:)
```

and called with

```
sayHello("Tim", alreadyGreeted: true)
```

You can see that `alreadyGreeted:` must be included in the function call, but not `personName`.

IIRC, the first argument in any function call is always omitted when calling the function but written out in the declaration (obviously, otherwise there would be no way to access it).